# What is the difference between insort_left and insort_right in bisect?

Tags: python

Why do both [`insort_left`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.insort_left) and [`insort_right`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#bisect.insort_right) exist; isn't it always the same result since the elements are equal?

```
>>> import bisect
>>> foo = [1,2,3]
>>> 
>>> bisect.insort_left(foo, 1)
>>> foo
[1, 1, 2, 3]
>>> 
>>> bisect.insort_right(foo, 1)
>>> foo
[1, 1, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Have you considered when the elements aren't equal?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For most purposes the results are indistinguishable, but there are cases where it can matter, particularly when using the optional `key=` argument.

Do you understand the difference between sorting algorithms that are, or aren't, guaranteed to be "[stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability)"? If not, click the link ;-)

```py
ys = []
for x in xs:
    bisect.insort_right(ys, x)
```

fills `ys` with a stable sort of `xs` entries, but using `insort_left()` instead would not.

Comment: It seems the `key` argument is new in 3.10, which explains why I didn't find it in the docs.

Comment: Doesn't really matter. For example, picture maintaining a sorted list of tasks to do, where the task objects compare using a `.priority` attribute. If you enter a new task, should it appear before or after any existing tasks of the same priority? "First come, first served" is implemented by one of `{insort_right, insort_left}`, and "most recent served first" by the other. There's nothing you can look at _in_ the task objects to make this distinction.

Answer (score 10):

Objects can be equivalent without being identical.

```
>>> bisect.insort_left(foo, 1.0)
>>> foo
[1.0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3]
>>> 
>>> bisect.insort_right(foo, 1.0)
>>> foo
[1.0, 1, 1, 1, 1.0, 2, 3]
```